# Deactivate localization for embedded resources

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

I'm facing the following problem right now:

In my project I have two embedded resources with the names

- test.en.js
- test.js

Calling `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()` lists only test.js. It took me a while to recognize that the internal localization system seem that "test.en.js" is the english version of test.js - but it isn't. The resources *need* to have these names. Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: What if you put them into different folders?

Comment: Doesn't work either. Folder is irrelavant for this scenario.